# Is it possible to use Kafka with Spring 4.1.0.RELEASE?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm working on a legacy project with Spring Version 4.1.0.RELEASE (no Spring Boot). Is there a way to integrate Kafka to the project? We need to consume and produce messages.

All I found on the internet about Spring + Kafka was about newer Spring versions and/or Spring Boot. Updating the project is unfortunately not an option. There is a parallel updating project for the application, but we need a short-time solution.

I tried to use spring-kafka 1.3.11.RELEASE, but I get an error while starting the application.

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.MethodIntrospector`

I found out that update to a newer Spring version would fix that. But as I said, updating Spring is not an option in this project context.

Comment: Even version 1.0.0 of `spring-kafka` uses Spring 4.2.x. It *might* work but you are probably going to run into similar issues. As Spring 4.1 is pretty old and not even supported anymore I would take some time to upgrade to a newer version.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @M.Deinum ! I total agree with you, with more time the right way would be upgrading Spring to a newer version. I interpret your answer as a 'no, it is not possible' and its ok. I just had to check if there is a way I didn't knew. Thank u!

Comment: Not upgrading will only make things worse. The 4.1 line has been out-of-support for ages already, and the only supported versions (today) are the 5.3 and 6.0 line. Postponing upgrading will only set you behind even more and the scare to upgrade will only be greater. At least upgrade to the latest 4.1.x version, from there gradually upgrade to newer versions doing 4.2/4/3/5.0/5.1/5.2/5.3. Take small steps, don't go to 5.3 in one go as you will drown in changes and broken things. Take small steps, it will also allow you to use all those other new nifty projects from spring.

Comment: Yeah sure, the spring upgrade process has been already started, but will take a while. It is part of a bigger infrastruction-migration project. We were just searching for a hot-fix solution for this kafka issue. To know that it's not possible is fine for us. We have a valid plan B. Thank you anyway for your advice!

Answer (score 0):

`kafka-clients` alone does not depend on Spring. You are not required to use `spring-kafka` , `spring-integration`, `spring-cloud-streams`, etc. dependendencies to "use Kafka with Spring", so if you don't mind wiring in the Kafka clients by yourself, then just start with the raw client library.