# Using Spring 4.0.5 (no spring boot) with spring-kafka 1.0.0 gives NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: spring, apache-kafka

I have tried to use kafka with Spring version 4.0.5 without Spring Boot.
I have used lowest version for Kafka since Spring version is also old and upgrading Spring right now is not possible

Below are newly added Maven dependency

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

I call`kafkaTemplate.send(message)`within a scheduled Quartz job and getting

ERROR JobRunShell - Job DEFAULT.jobAlertSenderTask threw an unhandled Exception:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/concurrent/SettableListenableFuture
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.doSend(KafkaTemplate.java:194) ~[spring-kafka-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate.send(KafkaTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-kafka-1.0.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.myProject.alertSender.kafka.KafkaMessageSender.send(KafkaMessageSender.java:60) ~[classes/:na]

Below is the pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.myProject.alertSender</groupId>
  <artifactId>alertSender</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>6.0.47.GA-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>alertSender Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.source.version>1.8</java.source.version>
    <java.target.version>1.8</java.target.version>
    <javax.servlet.version>3.0.1</javax.servlet.version>
    <org.springframework.version>4.0.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
    <org.springframework.security.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.security.version>
    <org.aspectj.version>1.8.2</org.aspectj.version>
    <spring-data-jpa.version>1.7.1.RELEASE</spring-data-jpa.version>
    <spring-data-rest.version>2.2.1.RELEASE</spring-data-rest.version>
    <spring-rabbit.version>1.3.9.RELEASE</spring-rabbit.version>
    <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
    <pgjdbc-ng.version>0.7</pgjdbc-ng.version>
    <org.slf4j.version>1.7.7</org.slf4j.version>
    <com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version>2.3.3</com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version>
    <org.hibernate.version>4.3.6.Final</org.hibernate.version>
    <org.quartz-scheduler.version>2.2.1</org.quartz-scheduler.version>
    <ch.qos.logback.version>1.1.2</ch.qos.logback.version>
    <hikaricp.version>2.4.7</hikaricp.version>
    <com.thoughtworks.xstream.version>1.4.7</com.thoughtworks.xstream.version>
    <hsqldb.version>2.3.2</hsqldb.version>
    <org.apache.poi.version>3.16</org.apache.poi.version>
    <net.schmizz.version>0.10.0</net.schmizz.version>
    <javax.mail.version>1.4.7</javax.mail.version>
    <org.springframework.expression.version>4.1.5.RELEASE</org.springframework.expression.version>
    <com.opencsv.version>3.3</com.opencsv.version>
    <org.apache.commons.version>3.10</org.apache.commons.version>
    <org.bouncycastle.version>1.46</org.bouncycastle.version>
    <com.osmoticweb.2wayfilter.version>1.2</com.osmoticweb.2wayfilter.version>
    <spring.ws.version>2.2.3.RELEASE</spring.ws.version>
    <castor.version>1.3.3</castor.version>
    <maven-artifact.version>3.0.5</maven-artifact.version>
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.1</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-resources-plugin.version>2.6</maven-resources-plugin.version>
    <maven-war-plugin.version>2.4</maven-war-plugin.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.3.1.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <lombok.version>1.18.12</lombok.version>
  </properties>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>repo_id</id>
      <url>repoURL</url>
   
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>jitpack.io</id>
      <url>https://jitpack.io</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>${junit.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>${hsqldb.version}</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
          <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
      <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
      <version>${com.thoughtworks.xstream.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-openid</artifactId>
      <version>3.1.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-security-acl</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.security.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
      <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
      <version>1.28.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
      <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
      <version>${org.aspectj.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-data-jpa.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-data-rest-webmvc</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-data-rest.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-rabbit.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-amqp</artifactId>
      <version>${spring-rabbit.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.impossibl.pgjdbc-ng</groupId>
      <artifactId>pgjdbc-ng</artifactId>
      <version>${pgjdbc-ng.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
      <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for Hibernate second level cache -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
      <version>${org.hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
      <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
      <version>2.6.11</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
      <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
      <version>${org.quartz-scheduler.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
      <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
      <version>${org.quartz-scheduler.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
      <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
      <version>${ch.qos.logback.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
      <version>${org.slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
      <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
      <version>${hikaricp.version}</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
      <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.poi.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.json</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>net.schmizz</groupId>
      <artifactId>sshj</artifactId>
      <version>${net.schmizz.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
      <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
      <version>${javax.mail.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.expression.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.opencsv</groupId>
      <artifactId>opencsv</artifactId>
      <version>${com.opencsv.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
      <version>${org.apache.commons.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
      <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15</artifactId>
      <version>${org.bouncycastle.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for version string comparison -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-artifact</artifactId>
      <version>${maven-artifact.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
      <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
      <version>${spring.ws.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
      <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibersap-core</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibersap-jco</artifactId>
      <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.myOrg</groupId>
      <artifactId>2wayfilter</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibersap</groupId>
      <artifactId>sapjco3</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
      <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.java-json-tools</groupId>
      <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.10</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- For easier validations of Pojos -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
      <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
      <artifactId>javax.el</artifactId>
      <version>3.0.1-b08</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-validator-annotation-processor</artifactId>
      <version>6.0.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
      <version>${com.fasterxml.jackson.core.version}</version>
    </dependency>



    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
      <version>${lombok.version}</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
      <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
      <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.jsonwebtoken/jjwt -->
    <dependency>
       <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
       <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
       <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- User Agent Detection-->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>eu.bitwalker</groupId>
      <artifactId>UserAgentUtils</artifactId>
      <version>1.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-all -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
      <version>1.10.19</version>
      <scope>test</scope>

    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.vladmihalcea</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-types-52</artifactId>
      <version>2.9.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
      <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
      <version>3.3.3</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>


    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.session/spring-session -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.session</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-session</artifactId>
      <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
      <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
      <version>4.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
      <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
      <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
      <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.keycloak</groupId>
      <artifactId>keycloak-core</artifactId>
      <version>11.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.annotation</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.annotation-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>alertSender</finalName>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-war-plugin.version}</version>
        <configuration>
          <attachClasses>true</attachClasses>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
          <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
          <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
              <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
              <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            </path>
            <path>
              <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
              <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
              <version>${lombok.version}</version>
            </path>
            <!-- other annotation processors -->
          </annotationProcessorPaths>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Comment: can you share your full pom.xml file? is `spring-core-*.jar` is part of your pom.xml and classpath?

Comment: I have added  the pom contents

Comment: According to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75436254/is-it-possible-to-use-kafka-with-spring-4-1-0-release  tells that the spring version 4 is outdated to use with kafka

Comment: Is it true that I can only use Kafka if I upgrade Spring version to 4.2 or higher?

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/util/concurrent/SettableListenableFuture.html shows that org.springframework.util.concurrent.SettableListenableFuture is only available from Spring version 4.1